# In WSO2 ESB, how to pass parameter to sequence from scheduler task

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I configured a scheduler task to invoke a sequence; and I need to pass a parameter to this sequence per requirement.  How to accomplish this in WSO2 ESB?  I had attempting to pass in the value through the message property in the scheduler task and read the value off the message in the sequence. But failed to obtain the value in the sequence.  My codes and output shown below.  Please let me know what I should do to make it work.  Thank you for your time in advance.

```
<task class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector" group="synapse.simple.quartz" name="UploadFile2Vendor1" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <trigger interval="15"/>
    <property name="message" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks">
       <request>
          <vendorId>1</vendorId>
       </request>
    </property>
    <property name="sequenceName" value="SendFile2VendorSeq" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
    <property name="injectTo" value="sequence" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
</task>

<sequence name="SendFile2VendorSeq" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <log>
    <property xmlns:m0="http://services.samples" 
  expression="$body/m0:request/m0:vendorId" name="vendorId"/>
  </log>
  <dblookup description="get vendor">
    <connection>
      <pool>
        <dsName>jdbc/DBDS</dsName>
      </pool>
    </connection>
    <statement>
      <sql>SELECT code, name FROM vendor WHERE id = ?</sql>
      <parameter expression="get-property('vendorId')" type="INTEGER"/>
      <result column="code" name="code"/>
      <result column="name" name="name"/>
    </statement>
 </dblookup>
</sequence>
```

Output in log file

```
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,446] DEBUG - StartUpController Synapse server name : localhost
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,446] DEBUG - StartUpController loaded task property : <property xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="injectTo" value="sequence"/>
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,446] DEBUG - StartUpController loaded task property : <property xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="sequenceName" value="SendFile2VendorSeq"/>
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,446] DEBUG - StartUpController loaded task property : <property xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="message">
  <request>
    <vendorId>1</vendorId>
  </request>
</property>

[2016-07-27 09:25:36,446] DEBUG - PropertyHelper Setting property :: invoking method setMessage(<request xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <vendorId>1</vendorId>
</request>)
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,446] DEBUG - MessageInjector set message <request xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <vendorId>1</vendorId>
</request>
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,446] DEBUG - TaskScheduler TaskScheduler already initialized.
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,532]  INFO - AbstractQuartzTaskManager Task scheduled: [-1234][ESB_TASK][Upload2Vendor]
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,532]  INFO - NTaskTaskManager Scheduled task [NTask::-1234::Upload2Vendor]
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,532] DEBUG - StartUpController Submitted task [Upload2Vendor] to Synapse task scheduler.
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,532] DEBUG - TaskDeployer Initialized the StartupTask : Upload2Vendor
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,532] DEBUG - TaskDeployer StartupTask Deployment from file : C:\MyApps\wso2esb-4.9.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1469629535899ESBCDRCApp_1.0.0.car\UploadCDR2CDG_1.0.0\Upload2Vendor-1.0.0.xml : Completed
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,532]  INFO - TaskDeployer StartupTask named 'Upload2Vendor' has been deployed from file : C:\MyApps\wso2esb-4.9.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1469629535899ESBCDRCApp_1.0.0.car\UploadCDR2CDG_1.0.0\Upload2Vendor-1.0.0.xml
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,532] DEBUG - SynapseArtifactDeploymentStore Added deployment artifact with file : C:\MyApps\wso2esb-4.9.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1469629535899ESBCDRCApp_1.0.0.car\UploadCDR2CDG_1.0.0\Upload2Vendor-1.0.0.xml
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,532] DEBUG - AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer Deployment of the synapse artifact from file : C:\MyApps\wso2esb-4.9.0\tmp\carbonapps\-1234\1469629535899ESBCDRCApp_1.0.0.car\UploadCDR2CDG_1.0.0\Upload2Vendor-1.0.0.xml : COMPLETED
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,532]  INFO - ApplicationManager Successfully Deployed Carbon Application : ESBCDRCApp_1.0.0 {super-tenant}
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,532] DEBUG - MessageInjector execute
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,532] DEBUG - Axis2SynapseEnvironment Creating Message Context
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,542] DEBUG - MessageInjector injecting message to sequence : SendFile2VendorSeq
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,542] DEBUG - Axis2SynapseEnvironment Injecting MessageContext for asynchronous mediation using the : SendFile2VendorSeq Sequence
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,552] DEBUG - SequenceMediator Start : Sequence <SendFile2VendorSeq>
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,552] DEBUG - SequenceMediator Sequence <SequenceMediator> :: mediate()
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,552] DEBUG - SequenceMediator Mediation started from mediator position : 0
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,552] DEBUG - SequenceMediator Building message. Sequence <SequenceMediator> is content aware
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,552] DEBUG - LogMediator Start : Log mediator
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,552]  INFO - LogMediator To: , MessageID: urn:uuid:c620513a-5b90-452e-8133-d5fd23e2cce0, Direction: request, vendorId = 
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,552] DEBUG - LogMediator End : Log mediator
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,552] DEBUG - DBLookupMediator Start : DBLookup mediator
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,582] DEBUG - DBLookupMediator Getting a connection from DataSource jdbc/CallOneCDRDB and preparing statement : 
SELECT SELECT code, name FROM vendor WHERE id = ?
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,662] DEBUG - DBLookupMediator Setting as parameter : 1 value : null as JDBC Type : 4(see java.sql.Types for valid types)
[2016-07-27 09:25:36,662] DEBUG - DBLookupMediator Successfully prepared statement : 
SELECT code, name FROM vendor WHERE id = ?
```

Comment: How would the message be generated/received? Couldn't you just preserve the vendorId in a property and then use it with get-property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option you can try is use `org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.TemplateMessageExecutor`
as the task class. This class exposes two parameters :

**1. templateParams**

You can set the parameters here in an XML in some root element.
Example :

```
<root>
   <user>John</user>
   <age>10</age>
</root>
```

**2. templateKey**
You can set the key of sequence template that uses the above parameters here.

Example : `gov:/sequenceTemplates/getUserSequenceTemplate`

**Sample Sequence Template**

```
<template name="getUserSequenceTemplate" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="user"/>
    <parameter name="age"/>
    <sequence>
        <log level = "full">
           <property name="User name is" expression={$func:user} />
           <property name="User age is" expression={$func:age} />
        </log>
    </sequence>
</template>
```

Comment: Hello maheeka, I will try this.  Do you have code example of a sequence template where it parse the parameter?  Thanks.

Comment: Added a sample sequence template

Comment: I had implemented this approach in my application.  Working as expected.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be issue with namespace. I have updated the task and sequence as follow. This worked for me.

Task

```
<task class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector" group="synapse.simple.quartz" name="UploadFile2Vendor1" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <trigger interval="15"/>
        <property name="message" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks">
           <request xmlns="" xmlns:m0="http://services.samples">
              <vendorId>1</vendorId>
           </request>
        </property>
        <property name="sequenceName" value="SendFile2VendorSeq" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
        <property name="injectTo" value="sequence" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
    </task>
```

Sequence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
          name="SendFile2VendorSeq"
          trace="disable">
   <log level="full"/>
   <log>
      <property   xmlns:m0="http://services.samples"
                name="vendorId"
                expression="//vendorId"/>
   </log>
</sequence>
```

Comment: Jenananthan, I replaced the log mediator with property mediator and corrected the xpath expression in my sequence. However, when I print the new property vendorId, I still do the value. The log looks like below    LogMediator To: , MessageID: urn:uuid:124b8764-bf35-41a4-b660-3cc22d60925c, Direction: request, message = vendorId =    Since this property will be passed into <DBLookup> mediator as a parameter, null value is passed in instead of 1.    DEBUG - DBLookupMediator Setting as parameter : 1 value : null as JDBC Type : 4(see java.sql.Types for valid types)

Comment: So I will say somehow the value of the property is not set.  Why?